# ERB file indentation is overridden by .rb settings

Tags: vim, indentation

I have the filetype plugin installed and using it. I have a ruby.vim file under `~/.vim/ftplugin/` that sets expandtab, softtabstop and shiftwidth.

I tried to do the same for .html.erb files, which seem to be of filetype `eruby`. I want my erb files to have tabs, and a tabstop and shiftwidth of 4, but vim, no matter what I put in eruby.vim, seems to always read ruby.vim after that, for some reason, and sets sts and sw just like I had opened a plain ruby file.

I also tried placing eruby.vim under `ftplugin/after/`, but I got the same results.

What is going on?

Comment: You meant you tried `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/eruby.vim`. Because `ftplugin/after` won't  work for sure.

Comment: No, I meant I tried `~/.vim/ftplugin/after/eruby.vim`, which is exactly why it didn't work. Answer to collect your bounty, then!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put the `eruby.vim` file in  `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/eruby.vim`. It should just fine.